# Copy all rows from each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the code. I want to merge all rows from few sheets except header in one sheet in Excel.

Here is the code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("P&L_consolidation")

For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Zero's" Then
       ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("U"& Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy sh.Range("A"& Rows.Count).ENd(xlUp)(2)
    End if
Next ws
```

This code works if the sheet has some data in it, but the problem is if some sheet contains only header then this code copy that header and paste it to the merged sheet. In that case I just want to skip that sheet.

Please, can somebody help me?

Comment: Set the range you want to copy to a variable, then just do an if statement such as `if myCopyRng.rows.count > 1 then [copy]`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("P&L_consolidation")

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Zero's" Then
            With ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))
                If .Row >= 2 Then .Copy wsDest.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```